# Partitions of a number for a fixed number of integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, terminology, integer-partitions

Is there a name for the number of ways to write a positive integer $n$ as a sum of $k$ integers, including 0?

For example, the number 4 can be written as the sum of 3 numbers in the following ways:

- 4+0+0
- 3+1+0
- 2+2+0
- 2+1+1

Note that $1+2+1$ counts as being the same as $2+1+1$. Also, the number 5 can be written as the sum of 3 numbers in the following ways:

- 5+0+0
- 4+1+0
- 3+2+0
- 3+1+1
- 2+2+1

Aside: If we wanted to treat $1+2+1$ as being *distinct* $2+1+1$, then the number of ways would be equivalent to the number of ways of choosing $k$ items from $n$ options (with replacement, and order does not matter): ${n + k -1 \choose k}.$

Is there a closed form expression for this number? If there was, let's call it $n_k.$ It would *not* follow that the total number of partitions is equal to $\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} n_k,$ because the fact that we allow $0$ means that this would overcount partitions.

Comment: Seems closely related to [partition of an integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory).)

Comment: These are restricted partitions and as far as I am aware there is not a closed form for general $n$ and $k$.  But for $k=3$ there is $\left[\frac1{12}(n + 3)^2\right]$  where $[\cdots]$ means "round to the nearest integer".  The total number of partitions of $n$ is the same as the number of restricted partitions of $n$ with $k \ge n$

Comment: @Henry Thank you. However, does the term "restricted partitions" generally not include '0' as a number. Furthermore, according to wikipedia, the formula you gave applies for the case where "in which all parts are 1, 2 or 3". However, I am considering 100=33+33+34 to be a partition, for example. Does that formula you gave also apply in this case?

Comment: So, since the linked article doesn't allow zero, but you do... consider adding $1$ to each of your parts and having a different total and compare the results.  E.g. $5+0+0=5$ is equivalent to $6+1+1=8$

Comment: The number of partitions of $n$ into up to three parts (or into exactly three parts with some parts equal to $0$) is the same as the number of partitions of $n$ into parts no greater than $3$ with a simple bijection between the two using Ferrers diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ways to write a positive integer $n$ as non-ordered sums of $k$ integers are called the partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts, or the strict partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts.

If the part $0$ is allowed, we have the partitions of $n$ with $0$ into $k$ parts, or the weak partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts.

Ordered integer partitions are called [integer compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

As Henry wrote in his comment, the number you ask is the number of partitions of $n$ into up to $k$ parts ([OEIS: A026820](https://oeis.org/A026820)).

See e.g. the books of MacMahon, Comtet or Charalambides.